# How do I remove a package installed via Chocolatey?

Tags: git-tfs, chocolatey

I installed gittfs using

`cinst gittfs`

How do I now remove the gittfs package?

Comment: I would like to suggest changing the accepted answer to the one by xuhdev

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chocolatey Uninstall Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402187/chocolatey-uninstall-package)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use

```
cuninst packagename
```

See [Uninstall Command](https://chocolatey.org/commands-uninstall) for details.

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE:** as per @ferventcoder's comment, Chocolately has added support for uninstalling packages since this question was first asked and answered.

The syntax is `chocolatey uninstall packageName` or just `cuninst packageName`.

You can optionally uninstall a specific version:

```
cuninst packageName -version 1.0.1234
```

See Rob's link for the latest, including known limitations:  https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-uninstall

Comment: Chocolatey now has native support for uninstall - see https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CommandsUninstall

Comment: It's the most frustrating thing that Chocolatey allows authors to submit packages with no uninstall procedure defined.

Comment: Choco does have autouninstaller since March 2015 and it's pretty good at automatically uninstalling applications now without an uninstall script.