# Uninstall Chocolatey package

Tags: installation, nuget, uninstallation, chocolatey

The Chocolatey package manager supports silent installations via the command below. It doesn't seem to have an uninstall command.

```
cinst install packagename
```

Is there a way to uninstall an application via Chocolatey?

Comment: foe those who end up here, the correct command now is `choco uninstall PackageName`

Answer (score 53):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353793/how-do-i-remove-a-package-installed-via-chocolatey), you can use

```
cuninst packagename
```

to uninstall a package.

Details can be found at [Uninstall Command](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-uninstall).

**Edit:** For new versions, should use `choco uninstall packagename`.

Comment: this is the correct way to uninstall anything from chocolatey

Comment: `Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage.ps1` & `UnInstall-ChocolateyZipPackage.ps1` are now provided within `%chocolateyinstall%\helpers\functions` (at least in v>=0.9.8.20).  You could `<requires>` this version of chocolatey or [review the trunk and determine which version contains both helper functions](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/commit/3cbdc56f8699e5d6fe8277cf950d8ab104eefad6#src/helpers/functions).

Comment: Just spoke to Rob Reynolds in #chocolatey on freenode and he stated that these helper functions aren't ready for prime time yet, so avoid their use for a bit.  When they are ready they will be listed here: [Contibute](http://chocolatey.github.io/contribute.html) and/or [Helpers Reference](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/HelpersReference).

Comment: Yes but it does not work. It says done. But it did nothing eg for the nodejs.install package. It could at least say : I am sorry I cant do that.

Comment: It's now `choco uninstall packagename` (cinst is going soon)

Answer (score 18):

**Update**: Chocolatey now has primitive support for uninstall through 'cuninst packagename'. With that though the package authors need to provide a chocolateyUninstall.ps1 file that would undo all of the things that the install did. It's limited because

- There are no functions defined in the Chocolatey PowerShell module that would help with uninstall
- There is no automatic removal of MSIs
- Uninstall only removes the most current version of a package in the machine repository (instead of giving you options to remove a certain one or all of them)

Comment: regarding your last point, it's actually possible via: >chocolatey uninstall nunit -version 2.5.7.10213
Source: https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CommandsUninstall/5b07bfce32d5069f8640883f69c2378481f10801#wiki-examples

Comment: Uninstall command currently ignores the version argument and defaults to the latest version (see https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CommandsUninstall), so there is no possibility to uninstall specific version.

Comment: Most of these comments have been addressed. https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-uninstall is the updated link for this now.