# chocolatey: cuninst alias vs choco uninstall

Tags: chocolatey

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11291823/8896457) answer I can read:

"For new versions, should use `choco uninstall packagename`."

Does it mean that `cuninst`, `cup`, `cinst` will get deprecated? Is it better to use `choco uninstall` ?

I see no such info in chocolatey [docs](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-uninstall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely a move away from the aliases that are being shipped with Chocolatey.  For example, there is a known issue with the `cpack` alias, which causes problems when you also have CMake installed on the machine.  This has been handled in the documentation for the command here:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-pack

Notice the mention of is being deprecated.  Also, I would suggest following this issue for additional information about potential deprecations:

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/89

Personally, I would recommend that you move away from using the aliases, and instead, use the full command, for example:

`choco upgrade all`

`choco install ...`

`choco uninstall ...`

etc.

Comment: Good idea to read this GitHub issue, thank you! It seems there is not definitely a move away from aliases. So I think I will use those which are not deprecated

Comment: Is the move away the reason why the aliases do not make their way into the PS aliases you see with the alias command?